# remove the .html from the end of a URL if there are two times in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Remove the .html from the end of a URL, if there are two times occurred in magento 2

Where should i change? in htaccess file or any other file

I write this code in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if there are two times occurred"? Can you give an example of a URL like the one you mean?

Comment: url: /mittal/magento/index.php/electronics.html.html
here '.html' occure two times in the last of url